# SQL Server Linked Server to Progress is slow with an openquery view

Tags: sql-server, view, linked-server, progress-database

We have a SQL Server database setup with a Linked Server setup connecting to a Progress OpenEdge database.  We created a SQL Server view (for using with SSRS) of some of the OpenEdge tables using code similar to the following:

```
CREATE VIEW accounts AS SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServerName,
'SELECT * FROM PUB.accounts')

CREATE VIEW clients AS SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServerName,
'SELECT * FROM PUB.clients')
```

For some reason the queries seem to bring back the whole table and then filter on the SQL side instead of executing the query on the Progress side.  I'm a dev and not a DBA so I'm hoping the experts can hook me up with a solution or at least an explanation as to why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did was dump the views all together and added sprocs that perform the openquery with the limited set of return values and a restricted where clause.  We also worked with progress and there was some optimizations they recommended on their side as well.  Performance still isn't great but it's much better than it was.  We are migrating from a Progress backend to a SQL and this was a step to enable Report Designer which it accomplished.  We aren't going to start delving into performance much more until after the data is migrated to the SQL Server environment completely.

Answer (score 0):

in your query above, every time some one views your view, an `OPENQUERY` is executed to your server

why don't you run a job that transfers the data from your progress server to your sql server and create a view pointing to a table in your server locally.

that will be much faster

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[copydatafromProgress]
AS
BEGIN

insert into tbl_accounts
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServerName,'SELECT * FROM PUB.accounts')

insert into tbl_clients
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServerName,'SELECT * FROM PUB.clients')

End



CREATE VIEW accounts AS SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts
CREATE VIEW clients AS SELECT * FROM tbl_clients
```

after that create a job that runs the stored procedure once a day or depending on the schedule you need.